# Where to insert placeholder function when using Promise?

Tags: javascript

I want to show a placeholder when I use Axios to get data from API.  I have just started using Promise, so I am not quite sure if the following is a good practice.  Is it correct to render placeholder before the Promise?  Is there any better alternative?

```
renderPlaceholder()

axios
      .post('http://example.com', {
        identifier: username.value,
        password: password.value
      })
      .then(response => {
        removePlaceholder();
        console.log('Done');
      })
      .catch(error => {

        console.log('An error occurred');
      });
```

Comment: This seems like a correct approach, indeed. 1) start showing placeholder 2) start process 3) when completed (`then()`): hide/remove placeholder.

Comment: You seem to not do anything with the placeholder in case of an error.